# How to pass REST tokens between urls? (Express.js)

Tags: node.js, rest, express, token

After saving the received token to the database, how do I pass the key to other URLs? Let's say, I have the following function:

```
function authenticate(req, res) {
   .... 
   var data = JSON.parse(data); // assume this is the token
   connection.query(queries['token_create'], [data.key, data.token]); // save to db
   res.redirect('/logged/index'); //redirect
}
```

Along with the redirect, I want to pass the received key. I don't want to pass it through URL (`/logged/index?key=meKey`) as this will not be safe.

Thank you

Comment: If security is a concern, you may wish to establish a secure connection. As for the session token, try using cookies instead.

Comment: You should separate this method (/login) and and pass the token into response. Then you can save it into localStorage and redirect user to index page.

Comment: How will I pass the key to other functions, so I can retrieve the token from localStorage/db?